# Hybrid Vehicle Simulation with State of Charge Information

Tags: sumo

My fellow researchers and I have been using SUMO for a bit of time now, and have been helped greatly by the informative posts here in the past - so I just wanted to share some appreciation ahead of time :)

My question is: Is it possible to append a Hybrid Vehicle model in the PHEM program files seen below?:
https://github.com/planetsumo/sumo/tree/master/sumo/src/utils/emissions

Ideally, this hybrid vehicle would be able to include the State of Charge (SOC) control and include the temporal changes of SOC as the vehicle travels according to the drive cycle, just as there are temporal changes to Fuel Consumption, emissions, etc. If possible, we would hope to create a new column for SOC information in the *emissionsDrivingCycle* output cited here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Emissions#emissionsDrivingCycle

Our team was thinking that it would be great to use the *emissionsDrivingCycle* tool with this new vehicle type, as we could use the standard vehicle definitions in PHEMLight, and define traffic in the standard ways. Essentially we are wondering: 1) Is it feasible to implement a Hybrid Vehicle energy balance model in the PHEM files, and 2) Could these files then be compiled to form a new version of the existing *emissionsDrivingCycle* tool?

Before we started to play around too much, we thought it would be best to ask the group first to see what the community might have to say.

Thank you all once again!

Regards,

Van

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are several PHEMlight emission types available but there is currently no hybrid. The problem with hybrids is, that you need essentially to change the emission model while the vehicle is running from combustion to electric (and vice versa) and there may be very different strategies in place for doing so. I would propose to make this change rather explicit than hiding it in an additional emission model file which can do nothing but average over all the different strategies out there. So you can switch emission models in a running simulation simply by giving a new vehicle type to an existing vehicle using TraCI. In Python this would be
`traci.vehicle.setType`.